# Compile Error: Declaration of Sonata\Translation Bundle\Block\LocaleSwitcherBlockService::validate Block()

Tags: symfony, doctrine, bundle, admin, sonata

This is my composer.json require content

```
  "require": {
       //Some stuff
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "*",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master"
```

The project is working except for when I open a form create or edit Then I get this error:

> Compile Error: Declaration of
>   Sonata\TranslationBundle\Block\LocaleSwitcherBlockService::validateBlock()
>   must be compatible with
>   Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockAdminServiceInterface::validateBlock(Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement
>   $errorElement, Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface $block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Fix, 
in the sonata_translation.yml file:
I set

gedmo:
    enabled: false

instead of

gedmo:
    enabled: true